# Diagonalize a many-body Hamiltonian

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, many-body, ground-state

Assume we start with a generic many-body Hamiltonian:
$$
H=\sum_{ij} t_{ij} a_i^\dagger a_j+\sum_{mnlk}U_{mnkl}a_{m}^{\dagger}a_{n}^{\dagger}a_la_k.
$$
Now if there is only the one-body part, which has a matrix form we can perform a series of canonical transformations to diagonalize it using a naive but effective way like Jacob's method.

*My question* is for the two-body term, the operator is kind of like a (rank-4)tensor, so I am wondering whether there is a general mathematical way to diagonalize the problem like Jacob's method. After that, the Hamtonlian will have the following form:
$$
H'= \sum_{I} \epsilon_I a_I^\dagger a_I+\sum_{IJ}\epsilon_{IJ}a_{I}^{\dagger}a_{J}^{\dagger}a_Ja_I+\text{higher body term}
$$

Comment: To be clear, you are asking for whether one can diagonalize a Hamiltonian of the form of your first equation but where one body terms are all zero, right $t_{ij}=0$? And that you expect the answer to have the form of your second equation?

Comment: Actually, you can consider we first diagonalize the one body part, which corresponds to a Fourier transformation(change of basis), then start to "diagonalize" the two-body part. The problem is there is a general method to diagonalize the one-body part since it resembles a lot like a matrix with only two indices, and the two-body part can then be considered as a rank-4 tensor, However, I don't know any existing method that can systematically help me to get the form I describe in the second equation.

Comment: @ZhiYuFan So in essence, you are asking if there is a standardized (and efficient) way to bring a Hamiltonian of the form of the first equation into the form of the second equation, where the "higher body terms" are interactions with at least 5 creation/annihilation operators? -- Do you have any constraints on the transformation? In which way to $H$ and $H'$ have to be related?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch A standard way would be using the BCH formula.

Comment: @ZhiYuFan In don't understand your comment. My question is: Should H and H' be related by a unitary? Is it sufficient if H' has the same low-energy spectrum as H? Or what does H' have to satisfy (i.e. how does it have to relate to H) to be a valid answer to your question?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, In principle H' should have the same spectrum or low-energy spectrum if you want, but has a form like the second formula.

Comment: @ZhiYuFan I think if you want the the low-energy spectrum of H' is the spectrum of H, you can find some construction where you just add some ancillas to H to make it higher-body, and then use your "leading" terms to ensure the low-energy space is that of H.

Answer (score 3):

In general case this Hamiltonian is not exactly solvable - in fact, there are many methods and approximations developed for dealing with such Hamiltonians in various situations, just to give a few examples:

- various mean-field approaches - like Hartree-Fock or Habbard-Stratonovich
- perturbation methods - e.g., Dyson expansion
- non-perturbative techniques, like renormalization group

In fact, finding the ground state of this Hamilronian is already an achievement - see [*Why is the ground state important in condensed matter physics?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591584/247642)

*However, in some special cases (i.e., for particular choices of $U_{mnkl}$) it can be solved exactly, using bosonization or Bethe-Ansatz.*

**Related**
I suggest looking for inspiration (for more precise questions) in the following threads (I didn't put them in any particular order):
[*Is there a way to guess/find unitary transformations for Hamiltonians?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/662088/247642)
[*Why is Hartree-Fock considered a mean-field approach?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647350/247642)
[*Is Hartree-Fock a standard mean field approximation?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/670635/247642)
[*Higher-order perturbation in Kondo problem*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/749214/247642)
[*What Are Some Examples of Physics Problems With Many Different Approaches That Give the Same Answer?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/631667/247642)
[*In what ways does quantum field theory (QFT) extend quantum mechanics (QM)?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/740325/247642)
[*Can Fermi liquid be obtained by a canonical transformation?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/682615/247642)

**Update (in response to the OP edit)**
The OP suggests looking more specifically at Hamiltonian
$$
H'= \sum_{I} \epsilon_I a_I^\dagger a_I+\sum_{IJ}\epsilon_{IJ}a_{I}^{\dagger}a_{J}^{\dagger}a_Ja_I+\text{higher body term}
$$
Note that
$$\sum_{IJ}\epsilon_{IJ}a_{I}^{\dagger}a_{J}^{\dagger}a_Ja_I=
\sum_{IJ}\epsilon_{IJ}n_{I}n_{J},$$
where
$n_I=a_{I}^{\dagger}a_I$ is the occupation number. The Hamiltonian without "higher body terms" (which are really still two-body, but representing the exchange interaction) is significantly simpler, and enters a number of well-known models, depending on $\epsilon_I, \epsilon_{IJ}$ and the meaning of indices $I,J$. Notably: Hubbard model, Anderson model, various models of Coulomb blockade, Tomonaga-Luttinger model, etc. Some of these are exactly solvable (Tomonaga-Luttinger, Anderson), for others there exist well developed approximate methods and non-perturbative results.

Comment: The term "Bogoliubov" should probably be in there too (to make it easier to search for the associated approximate diagonalization techniques), although I suppose that's all wrapped up in your first bullet point.

Comment: @march I thought about including it... but I had doubts, since it is really applied to a bilinear Hamiltonian, after mean field approximation.

Comment: Well, that makes sense, but there is, after all, [Hartree-Fock Bogoliubov](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hartree-Fock+Bogoliubov&sca_esv=579886644&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS1053US1059&sxsrf=AM9HkKkMlanbyVlgwbdlIQx0EuKabQRRrg%3A1699300151006&ei=NkNJZYmEPY7B0PEPjfeViAI&ved=0ahUKEwiJ9_eukrCCAxWOIDQIHY17BSEQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=Hartree-Fock+Bogoliubov&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiF0hhcnRyZWUtRm9jayBCb2dvbGl1Ym92MgcQABgeGLADSIfxAVAAWABwA3gAkAEAmAE3oAE3qgEBMbgBA8gBAOIDBBgBIEGIBgGQBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I guess all the methods here are essentially a perturbative point of view. I guess I am asking this problem from a different perspective.

Comment: @ZhiYuFan see the update in response to your edit.

Comment: @RogerV. I am aware of interaction like the Hubbard model, but the problem is if I diagonalize the one-body part first then the two-body term would not be in an ideal form so I need to perform canonical transformation again, but generally for the two-body part I don't know whether there is a generic way to get the second form.

Comment: @ZhiYuFan there is no general way to solve this Hamiltonian - this is why people developed model Hamiltonians, approximations, perturbative methods, renormalization group, etc. I suggest that you ask a new question explaining more precisely the problem that you are dealing with.

Comment: @RogerV. Indeed, I will organize my question better and start a new one.